# jQuery - .length() counts special chars as 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, char

I have this problem when i use `$('#id').val().length;` it returns `2` when I use characters like `æ`, `ø` and `å`.

Can someone tell me why and how I can get it to work like ( one ) char?

Comment: Are you sure there are no space. What happens if you try `"æ".length`?

Comment: I have a feeling this has something to do with UTF-8 combining characters - there are two valid ways to write a lot of characters in UTF one as a single character and one as a pair... it causes a lot of headaches but I don't know enough to really answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect something else is going on here and it is not an issue of encoding.

I refuse to believe this is a jQuery issue (see http://jsfiddle.net/KLzYf/ for my jsutification).

The following raw HTML will report back "1":

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" value="æ" id="test"/>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById("test").value.length);
</script>

</html>
```

I'd be interested to see some of the HTML/other code. And to have a few tests, for instance, what do the following give you

```
alert("æ".length);  //=1?
alert('"' + $('#id').val() + '"'); //are there any spaces/other chars?
```

Also, if you view-source on the HTML, what do the contents of your input look like.

Comment: Thanks thats is my problem UTF-8 :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Innuendo108/GXwGG/

There are 2 characters and it says length=2

Answer (score 1):

I think you used extra space either or any one side of that character.

```
<p id="t">&aelig;</p>
$('#t').text().length
```

This work properly.

Comment: I think you've missed the space out :-)